# Force MySQL to return a result for all option within IN

Tags: mysql, count, return, return-value

I have a simple MySQL statement:

```
SELECT q1, COUNT(q1) FROM results WHERE q1 IN ('1','2','3');
```

Currently there are only results for 1 and 3 - results are:

```
1 = 6
3 = 7
```

But what I need is for MySQL to bring back a result for 1,2 and 3 even though 2 has no data, as this:

```
1 = 6
2 = 0
3 = 7
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't your code just *assume* it's zero if it's not in the data set?

Comment: Not sure how I would go about bringing the results back into an array and forcing the code to pick up where the gaps are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky because no rows match your value (2), they cannot be counted.

I would solve this by creating a temp table containing the list of values I want counts for:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE q ( q1 INT PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO q (q1) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

Then do an OUTER JOIN to your results table:

```
SELECT q.q1, COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS count
FROM q LEFT OUTER JOIN results USING (q1)
GROUP BY q.q1;
```

This way each value will be part of the final result set, even if it has no matching rows.

---

Re comment from @Mike Christensen:

MySQL doesn't support CTE's, in spite of it being requested as far back as 2006: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244

You could do the same thing with a *derived table*:

```
SELECT q.q1, COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS count
FROM (SELECT 1 AS q1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN results USING (q1)
GROUP BY q.q1;
```

But this creates a temp table anyway.

Comment: Probably possible with a CTE as well.  Not sure if mySQL supports those yet.

Comment: 2006?  Yeesh!  I guess this shows how much MySQL cares about keeping up with standards.

Comment: They haven't done much to improve their SQL language support, but they've spent a lot of effort improving the internals of the storage engine, to make MySQL more stable and more scalable. That part has paid off. But yeah, MySQL seems kind of stagnant from the developer point of view.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query doesn't really have a way to refer to the values in your `IN` clause.  I think you'd have to break this down into one query for each value.  Something like:

```
SELECT 1 as q1, COUNT(1) FROM results WHERE q1 = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as q1, COUNT(1) FROM results WHERE q1 = '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as q1, COUNT(1) FROM results WHERE q1 = '3'
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96822/1)

**Note:** If there are a *lot* of values in your `IN` clause, you might be better off to write your code in a way where *missing values* are assumed to have zero.

Comment: How resource intensive is that...for example, if I had not 20 but say 400?

Comment: @Homer_J - Honestly I don't know.  MySQL might be able to optimize it and do one table scan or one index scan, but you'd have to run some tests to see.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot query something that does not exists. So, you must create data for it. Use union to add those missing data values.

```
select q1, COUNT(*) 
from results 
where q1 in ('1','2','3')
group by q1
union
select q1, 0
from (
  select '1' as q1
  union 
  select '2'
  union 
  select '3'
) as q
where q1 not in (
  select q1
  from results
)
```